# The special embedding $\mathfrak{so}(7)\subset\mathfrak{so}(8)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, spin-geometry, exceptional-groups

It is commonly known that we have a chain of embeddings

$$SU(4)\subset Spin(7)\subset SO(8)$$

(there is more than one possible $Spin(7)$, just take one).

**Which is the explicit analog for the Lie Algebras embeddings? How may we describe the 21-dimensional space corresponding to $\mathfrak{so}(7)$ in**

$$\mathfrak{su}(4)\subset \mathfrak{so}(7)\subset \mathfrak{so}(8)$$

**according to their matrices?**

And also,

**How to characterise the image of a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{so}(7)$?**

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You'll find all of this and more in F. R. Harvey's book "Spinors and Calibrations".

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you very much!! Which chapter / page approximately?

Comment: Look at the material in Chapter 14 in the section "Triality", where $\mathrm{Spin}(7)\subset\mathrm{SO}(8)$ is described as the group generated by $R_u$ for $u\in S^6\subset\mathrm{Im}(\mathbb{O})$. (He's identifying $\mathbb{R}^8$ with $\mathbb{O}$, the octonions.)  While the Lie *algebra* isn't written out explicitly there, it follows immediately from Harvey's Lemma 14.66 that ${\frak{spin}}(7)\subset{\frak{so}}(8)$ is the space of skew-symmetric matrices orthogonal to all the skew-symmetric matrices $R_u$ for $u\in\mathrm{Im}(\mathbb{O})$.

Comment: Oh, also:  Any Cartan subalgebra of ${\frak{su}}(4)$ is also a Cartan subalgebra of ${\frak{spin}}(7)$, since both these groups have rank $3$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you...! Your answers are simply brilliant, they always help me a lot.